# PyPy on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: python, win64, pypy

I am trying to use PyPy on a Windows 7 x64 machine but do not find any way to do it.
Apparently there is a win32 binary, but no x64 binary or installation guide.
I am currently using Python 2.7.2 win64 (Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32).

Installation from sources raised the following error:

> [translation:ERROR]  WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Does anyone have a guide/hint to use PyPy on a win64?
Or is it just not possible?

Comment: PyPy now supports 64-bit Windows. See https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/windows64.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit PyPy now supports Windows. They wrote a post about how they were finally able to add support (https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/windows64.html). If you go to their downloads page, they have 64-bit Windows downloads available (https://www.pypy.org/download.html).

Answer (score 16):

PyPy is not compatible with 64bit windows. Primary reason is that sizeof(void*) != sizeof(long) which is a bit annoying. Contributions are more than welcome :)

Comment: Who took the decision to assume that sizeof(void*) == sizeof(long)? Very poor decision.

Comment: You need an int type that fits pointer. long made sense for most platforms, will require a bit of mangling to make this run on win64. Agreed, not the best decision.

Comment: sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void*) at least using msvc compiler

Comment: Also, there is intptr_t type.

Comment: Yes, we'd use a type like ``intptr_t`` systematically.  It's not that hard, but someone needs to do it.  None of us has any 64-bit Windows machine, even on remote access.

Comment: Nowadays it is easy to setup your build environment on CI such as appveyor.

Comment: Hi Fijial, do you know if any progress has been made on this point?

Comment: No progress has been done so far. Unless we find volunteers or funding it'll not happen on its own

Answer (score 6):

There's no version available for 64 bit Python on Windows. You appear to have the following options:

1. Download the source to PyPy and port it to 64 bit.
2. Switch to 32 bit Python.

Option 2 looks more tractable.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer.
I'll stick to the 32 bit version then.

Answer (score 3):

Just an update on this issue if anyone read it nowadays: PyPy seems to have solved their issues with Windows x64, you can download the 32-bit version of PyPy and it will work flawlessly under Windows 7 x64 (I even have a 64-bit python install beside, and pypy is working nicely along, I just have to specify the full path to pypy to use it for the scripts I need).

Comment: I don't think there was ever any issue to run the 32-bit PyPy on the Windows 64 OS.  The original question was about the 64-bit PyPy, which doesn't exist so far.

Comment: @ArminRigo no the OP asked a way to use PyPy on Win64. He probably guessed that only 64-bit PyPy would run on his platform, but in fact that's not necessary, 32-bit PyPy runs perfectly well.

Comment: (5 years later) yes I was able to run the 32-bit one and was looking for a way to run 64-bit